# How do I build an older version of Blender from source code?

Tags: source-code

I'm a beginner and I'm building Blender from source code for the first time.
By using this URL "https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows", I was able to build the latest alpha version of 3.0 without any problems.

Next I want to build an older version such as 2.8 or 2.9, but I don't know how.
I know that you can download the source code for the old version from Blender's HP.

However, as it is, the ".git" folder does not exist, so it cannot be built.
So, I created a new ".git" folder with the git init command, but when compared to the 3.0 ".git" folder that was successfully built, the build fails because the required files are not enough.
So even if I copy and run the 3.0 ".git" folder, the build fails.

As a beginner, I don't know what's right and what's wrong.
I would like to know how to build from an older version of the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

git clone -b branch_or_tag_name repo_address_or_path

further info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555107/git-clone-particular-version-of-remote-repository

If you got to github and search the blender repository (https://github.com/blender/blender/tags) you can check which tags exist:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I was able to build the 2.9 series with the code and URL method you taught me.

Comment: if my answer helped you it would be very nice if you could click on that checkmark left to my answer. Thank you!